# RETURNING clause for PostgreSQL UPDATE with PHP/PDO

Tags: php, sql, postgresql, pdo

I execute a simple postgresql update as:

```
UPDATE data SET Gender=lower(tmp.champs2) 
FROM tmp WHERE data.email=tmp.champs1 
AND (data.Gender IS NULL OR data.Gender='') 
AND tmp.champs2 IS NOT NULL 
AND tmp.champs2!='' 
RETURNING Gender
```

The PostgreSQL documentation said we can get the number of rows affected with the RETURNING clause.

But how can I get this result with PHP, PDO?

I try something like:

```
echo $requete = "UPDATE data 
    SET ".$value."=lower(tmp.champs".$num.") 
    FROM tmp 
    WHERE data.email=tmp.champs".$email." 
    AND (data.".$value." IS NULL OR data.".$value."='') 
    AND tmp.champs".$num." IS NOT NULL 
    AND tmp.champs".$num."!='' 
    RETURNING ".$value;

    $db->exec($requete);

    $db->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM);

    echo $row[0];
```

The correct number of rows updated are not returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [PDO's doc](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.exec.php):

> PDO::exec() executes an SQL statement in a single function call,
>   returning the number of rows affected by the statement.

Your current code `$db->exec($requete);` ignores the return value, which is the mistake. This should be for instance:

```
$affected_rows = $db->exec($requete);
```

A `RETURNING` clause is not necessary to get the number of rows affected (besides, it doesn't exist in some backends that PDO supports). The purpose of `RETURNING` is to retrieve rows in addition to updating, all in the same query.

In the case where the `RETURNING` clause is necessary and results must be fetched, [`PDO::query`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php) should be used instead of [`PDO:exec()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.exec.php). The PHP code to fetch the results is the same as if the query was a `SELECT`.

Answer (score -1):

According to documentation you should use

```
$count = $db->rowCount();
```

Comment: I got a Fatal error: Call to undefined method PDO::rowCount()

Comment: instead of $db you should have your PDO object. Dont you have a  $db = new PDO("pgsql:dbname=pdo;host=localhost", "username", "password" );